# best way to update an SQL row

Tags: sql, objective-c

I have a SQL database that it is possible to update. As the sql (will be server based) i only want to update values as i need to. So if only one column changes, only one column updates.

I have a mechanism that detects if values have changed and currently i have a messy function that constructs the SQL syntax and then binds the data to it. What I'm wondering is, is there any value i can bind to the syntax so SQL dosn't update that column. So for example.

```
@"update TABLE1 Set col1 = ?, col2 = ? Where ROWID = '%d'",ROWID];
```

so if col2 hasn't changed is there any value i can bind to it so it don't update that column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically no, there is no "magic" value you can bind that will leave col2 unchanged.

Binding the old value (ie updating with the same value col2 already has) will give the desired effect but requires you to update a single row at a time and know the old value for each row.

Rebuilding the SQL to not include `col2` is most likely the right thing to do in most circumstances.

Comment: i'll leave it as constructing sql syntax, most entires are low quality image files to rewriting them every time will be resource heavy.

Answer (score 0):

Get all column values in some variables...say col1,col2.(for that specific row)

> If column1 is changed you may update variable col1 value.
>
> Similarly,If column2 is changed you may update variable col2 value.

and a single UPDATE QUERY you mentioned above should do the required updation.

Answer (score 0):

I dont' understand if you want to make unchanged a particular set of rows or you can select a random set of ROW ID.

if you can select a random set of row id you can perform the query as the following below :

```
    update TABLE1 Set col1 = ?, col2 = ? Where ROWID NOT IN ( SELECT ................. )
```

where the SELECT clause extraxt ROWIDs you don't want to update.